# java.io.EOFException on Android Client (API 23) when POSTing Object to Jersey

Tags: android, rest, jersey

I want to implement a basic authentication using an Android Client and a Glassfish 4.1.1 Server (communicating through REST-Service).
The Service is working quite well (proven by POSTMAN and another C#-Client) but on Android, it's driven me crazy by now.
It also appears that the object-to-send is received as 'null' on the server side, also an annoying "EOFException" is thrown on the Android Side. 
Server side (works fine)

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Account validate(Account acc)
{
   Account a = null;
   a = Database.getInstance().getAccountByUserPw(acc);
   return a;
}
```

Android Client:

```
public Account postData(String JSONtoSend)
{

    URL url;
    Account get = new Account();
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.xxx.xxx.x:18080/HolidayOutServer/webresources/validateacc");

        HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        urlCon.setDoOutput(true); // to be able to write.
        urlCon.setDoInput(true); // to be able to read.

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlCon.getOutputStream());


        out.write(JSONtoSend);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
        get = (Account) ois.readObject();

        return get;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return get;
}
```

which is called within this:

```
class help extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Account>
{

   @Override
   protected Account doInBackground(String... params) {
       return postData(new Gson().toJson(new Account("aleqs", "lexx", -2)));
   }
}
```

Problems in a nutshell:

- Jersey Server receives null
- Android throws this ridiculous EOFException.

Can somebody help ? 
Thanks in advance,
John.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find a solution here after hours.
This code works for me:

```
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( urlCon.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(new Gson().toJson(new Account("aleqs", "lexx", -2)).getBytes());
        }
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        response = sb.toString();
        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return response;
```

Change the return type of "donInBackGround" to String and let the helper class extend -String, Void, String-. 
MOST IMPORTANT: CHECK IF YOUR ATTRIBUTES ON CLIENT SIDE (eg. id, name, ..) match with those from SERVER SIDE.
Consider cap locks and so on..
Cheers !